# Comprobar si los arrays de un objeto javascript están todos vacíos

Tags: javascript

Partiendo de que tengo un objeto asi:

```
          var categorias = {
          value1 : [],
          values2 : [],
          values3 : []
          }
```

Quisiera saber cuando todos los array de las distintas propiedadas estan vacios. He intentando algo asi:

```
var keys = Object.keys(categorias)

           keys.forEach(e =>{
           if(categorias.e.length != 0){return true}
           console.log(categorias.e.length)
           })
```

Me error que no puedo acceder a la propiedad lenght. Entiendo que no es forma correcta de acceder a cada propiedad de categorias. No se me ocurre mas que variaciones a los mismo.
¿Alguna sugerencia?
Muchas gracias. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes Acceder a una propiedad de un objeto usando [literal notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) cuando iteras.

```
if(categorias.e.length != 0){return true} ✖
```

Para tal caso deberías usar la [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer), así:

```
if(categorias[e].length != 0){return true} ✔️
```

Para resolver tu pregunta puedes usar la function [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/some):

```js
var categorias = {
  value1 : [],
  values2 : [],
  values3 : []
}

var keys = Object.keys(categorias)

const result = keys.some(k => categorias[k].length)

console.log('is empty: ' + !result)
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Christian. Me ha sido util y las mas completa. Muchas gracias de nuevo

Answer (score 1):

Con un `for in` podrías recorrer cada propiedad del objeto y comprobar si cada propiedad esta vacía o tiene datos, lo haría algo como:

```js
var categorias = {
   value1 : [1],
   values2 : [],
   values3 : []
   }
      
      
   for(propiedad in categorias){
    if(categorias[propiedad] == 0){
     console.log("vacio");
    }else{
     console.log("tiene datos");
    }
   }
```

Comment: esto claro lo puedes meter en una función para que después del for retornes true y retorna false dentro del if de est vacio

Answer (score 1):

Partiendo de la base del código que nos has puesto, el fallo se encuentra en que para acceder a la propiedad usando un valor dinámico, tienes que usar los corchetes:

```
keys.forEach(e =>{
  if(categorias[e].length != 0){return true}
  console.log(categorias[e].length)
})
```

Y ya para contestar a la pregunta, usando `every` puedes comprobar si todos los elementos de un array cumplen la condición:

```
keys.every(e => categorias[e].length === 0)
```